# How to exclude a specific value in my sql query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, equality

I have the following query which outputs everything correctly except that I don't want one of the rows it's giving me:

```
SELECT r.Region_Cd, r.Region_Desc, 
COUNT(a.Region) AS Count
FROM Region r
--WHERE r.Region_Desc <> "Unspecified"
LEFT JOIN HU_UNIT_STATE_LEVEL a ON r.Region_Cd = a.Region
GROUP BY r.Region_Cd, r.Region_Desc;
```

I would like to exclude the entries where r.Region_Desc is "Unspecified" but I'm unsure about where to put the clause. I commented out the line that I thought would do the trick but ended up giving me an error. Could I also get an explanation as to why my current query doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Use where condition after join.

```
SELECT r.Region_Cd, r.Region_Desc, 
COUNT(a.Region) AS Count
FROM Region r
LEFT JOIN HU_UNIT_STATE_LEVEL a ON r.Region_Cd = a.Region
WHERE r.Region_Desc <> 'Unspecified'
GROUP BY r.Region_Cd, r.Region_Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot write a where condition for parent table from which we are trying to join the other tables.  But we can write a condition with other joining tables. so use condition after join.

```
SELECT r.Region_Cd, r.Region_Desc, 
COUNT(a.Region) AS Count
FROM Region r
LEFT JOIN HU_UNIT_STATE_LEVEL a ON r.Region_Cd = a.Region
WHERE r.Region_Desc <> 'Unspecified'
GROUP BY r.Region_Cd, r.Region_Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

By taking performance into consideration you should use something like this.

```
SELECT r.Region_Cd, r.Region_Desc, 
COUNT(a.Region) AS Count
FROM Region r
LEFT JOIN HU_UNIT_STATE_LEVEL a ON r.Region_Cd = a.Region and r.Region_Desc <> "Unspecified"
GROUP BY r.Region_Cd, r.Region_Desc;
```